# Why is scikitlearn implementation for dictionary learning faster than cvxpy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I am implementing a sparse matrix factorization routine to generate a sparse score matrix and a dense feature matrix in python. There is a direct implementation in scikit-learn `scikitlearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning` which works well for a matrix of size 1000x947 returning result in ~20s on 16 core AMD system with 16GB memory. Though it is fast and easy to work with I have to add additional constraints to the problem which necessitates using something like CVXPY toolbox. I am using 'SCS' solver on CVXPY toolbox but the alternative minimization formulation to minimize the sparse score matrix and dense feature matrix won't even run on my computer and takes several days on a HPC cluster. What am I missing?

```py
#Scikitlearn implementation
       estimator_RA = skd.dict_learning(data_RA, n_components=number_of_components_RA, alpha=alpha_value_RA, n_jobs=-1,
                                     verbose=False, positive_dict=True, positive_code=True)


# CVPY implementation
    MAX_ITERS = 10
    residual = np.zeros(MAX_ITERS)
    for iter_num in range(1, 1 + MAX_ITERS):
        # At the beginning of an iteration, U and V are NumPy
        # array types, NOT CVXPY variables.

        # For odd iterations, treat U constant, optimize over V.
        if iter_num % 2 == 1:
            V_RA = cp.Variable((k_RA, n_RA))
            constraint = [V_RA >= 0]
            # constraint += [cp.norm2(V_RA, 1) <= np.ones((V_RA.shape[0],))]

            print('Estimating V')
        # For even iterations, treat V constant, optimize over U.
        else:
            U_RA = cp.Variable((m_RA, k_RA))
            constraint = [U_RA >= 0]

            print('Estimating U')

        # Solve the problem.
        # increase max iters otherwise, a few iterations are "OPTIMAL_INACCURATE"
        # (eg a few of the entries in U or V are negative beyond standard tolerances)
        obj = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(data_RA - U_RA * V_RA, 'fro') + alpha_value_RA * cp.pnorm(U_RA, 1))


        prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraint)
        prob.solve(solver='SCS', max_iters=1000, verbose=True, use_indirect=True)

        if prob.status != cp.OPTIMAL:
            raise Exception("Solver did not converge!")

        print('Iteration {}, residual norm {}'.format(iter_num, prob.value))
        residual[iter_num - 1] = prob.value

        # Convert variable to NumPy array constant for next iteration.
        if iter_num % 2 == 1:
            V_RA = V_RA.value
        else:
            U_RA = U_RA.value
```